# C: print value of macro

Tags: c, macros

I am working with C legacy code. In the code, a macro is used:

```
static int _main(A_MACRO *input_obj)
{
 ....
```

I am not sure what data type A_MACRO declares input_obj to be. How can I print this information to the screen?

I tried to do it like this:

```
static int _main(A_MACRO *input_obj)
{
sprintf("%s is the macro", A_MACRO);
....
```

but that resulted in this error message:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Comment: "I am working with C legacy code" - So why added the tag for a different language? And provide a [mcve].

Comment: What compiler are you using? `gcc -E` is emitting the preprocessed code. But it could be easier just to `grep` out all of the occurences of `#define A_MACRO`..

Comment: You need to find in the codebase where this macro is defined.  Run `grep "#define.*A_MACRO" *.c *.h` to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "stringize" macro which converts the definition to a string like so:

```
#define STRINGIZE_(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_(x)
```

Then you just "call" it with the macro name:

```
printf("A_MACRO is defined as %s\n", STRINGIZE(A_MACRO));
```

---

Alternatively, depending on the compiler you're using, it might have an option for displaying macro definitions. For example, with `gcc` you can use the `-dM` option:

```
gcc -dM file.c | grep A_MACRO
```

Comment: You need two-leveled implementation of `STRINGIZE(x)` for that to work with arguments which themselves are macros. What you have now will simply print `"A_MACRO"` string, not the actual "value" of `A_MACRO` macro. First, `#define STRINGIZE_(x) #x`, then `#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_(x)`.

Comment: @AnT Two level implementation is not working it's printing "A_MACRO" I think the only way is `-dM` flag.

Comment: Are you sure `A_MACRO` is a macro?

Comment: @Nick: Exactly. Could it be that `A_MACRO` is a typedef-name and not really a macro at all? That would explain why even two-leveled `STRINGIZE` still prints mere `"A_MACRO"` string.

Comment: @Nick: C language does not have `assert` macro. It has `assert(x)` macro, i.e. a macro *with a parameter*. If a macro is defined with a parameter, then macro name alone is not replaced as a macro by the preprocessor. So, in your case `assert` is not recognized as a macro,